# Server error with large posts

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, database, timeout, drupal

On a large drupal site, the database server is on a separate server connected directly to the web server. The web server uses apache and memcached. The problem is that whenever the post is a large, say larger than 10KB, the server does not return correctly. I checked both apache and mysql logs but could not find any trace of errors being logged. The error happens also when I use nginx/php5-fpm instead of apache.

Despite this, the large posts are registered, however incorrectly so that they show up for admin when I open a new page on the site. I'm really confused and appreciate your hints to pinpoint the possible sources if this chronic problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a memory and/or resources problem.

No guarantee it will help, but I think it's worth experimenting / checking:

- Increase the php memory limits by editing the following lines in the `php.ini` file as:

  - `max_execution_time = 30` --> `60` ;
  - `memory_limit = 32` --> `128`, or even `256`M ;
- Add the following lines to the end of `.htaccess` file:

  - `php_value auto_append_file none`
  - `php_value memory_limit 128M`

PS: is this Drupal version 7 (or still 6)?